OUAF Service script schema node type raw is not showing
I am using the groovy members step type on a service script to capture an XML after invoking.
def myXml=evalElement('myGroup/myData').getElementsByTagName('myBody').item(0)
I can see the output of myXml as expected using loggers
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
<myBody>
.....whatever....
</myBody>

The script schema has a structure of
<parm>
  <output type="group">
    <childList type="list">
      <grandChildList type="list">
        <node1/>
        <node2/>
        <rawNode type="raw"/>
      </grandChildList
    </childList>
  </output>
</parm>

I am using postman to test this through IWS and it returns with no errors but whatever the node with type="raw" is not showing up on the response.
I also tried logging the raw node if it has content after the move function, and it did.
This is how I used the move method
//these lists have already been used before this line
move(myXml, "parm/output[last()]/childList[last()]/grandChildList[last()]/rawNode")

Any ideas? This myXml has no definite structure. I tried moving to a node with dataType group but it returns a jsonObject stack overflow exception.
Tried moving to string type but it says cant move to non container field.
I even put the raw type node to a simpler place outside lists but it just wont show on response.

You’re using the last() index for your move target path. This can sometimes be tricky if the path is not well-defined or if list indexing behaves differently in your environment. Try explicitly specifying the index, or make sure that the last() expression is functioning correctly. Replace last() with a specific index (e.g., [1] if you have only one element in each list): move(myXml, "parm/output[1]/childList[1]/grandChildList[1]/rawNode")

I did it without the complicated xpath when I put the raw node just under the output group, so my command was just move(myXml, "parm/output/rawNode") but still it did not show in the response

The part under "script schema" is not valid XML - but maybe it doesn't have to be? I'm not familiar with OUAF. If it has to be valid XML either you wrote the empty tags wrongly (<node1/> would be correct) or the opening tags are missing (e.g. <node1>). This is important as it could influence the true structure of the document.

My bad, yes the slashes should be at the end. This should be not an issue in OUAF since it validates formatting before saving the schema.

This is not a direct solution, but a workaround -- instead of settling on type="raw", I declared every single data area as groups right inside the script schema, and just wrote logic to identify which data area to use when.
